# Silex 500 Error Off The Bat

Tags: php, silex

This is a very noob question.  I'm basically just trying to run the "hello world" of Silex.  I've installed the silex.phar file in my directory, setup the .htaccess file as such:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /projects/silex/  ###--> commented out because file is in root dir. <--##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and then run these two lines of code on the index.php file:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar';

$app = new Silex\Application();
```

I am getting a 500 internal server error. ("File does not exist")

I am running php 5.3.8 on Linux.

Is there a PHP setting I should be looking for?

Comment: Look into the `error.log` for the actual error message.

Comment: The error is "File does not exist"...

Comment: Well, since only you know the name of the missing file at this point, you must fix this yourself.

Comment: it doesn't get much simpler than this...
http://i.imgur.com/Q4xOx.png

Comment: not to mention I told you the name of the file in the third sentence of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug called the phar-stub bug.  It will tell you that Silex\Application could not be found. A workaround is using the following include line:

```
require_once 'phar://'.__DIR__.'/silex.phar/autoload.php';
```

[source](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#phar-stub-bug)

Comment: Can you check if the PHP `detect_unicode` setting is enabled? And if it is, can you disable it (set it to `Off`) and try again without the `phar://`? Cheers.

Comment: @igor2 this seems to have worked.  I have another question for you... I seem to be having a lot of trouble using the DoctrineExtension (provider).  When I am running this usage example (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html) I get an error "Class 'PDO' not found in /home/hupcap/public_html/projects/silex/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 32"  have you heard of this before?  I've copied all the extension files from fabpot's silex folder on github (https://github.com/fabpot/Silex)

Comment: You don't need to copy the extension files, they are included in the phar. The error you're getting is because you don't have the PHP PDO extension. You'll have to enable/install that, it's a PHP core extension.

Comment: @igor,  Thank you.  It was an issue with my host.  Having this info let me drill them for not having the PDO class available!  Everything works great now.